# Store Session ID using NET core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core

I am learning NET core, slowly transiting from .Net Framework.
I have a piece of code that seems not to work as expected.
I am trying to save the session ID to the database once the user performs an action.
My code in .NET framework is simple as follows:

```
  public async Task<ActionResult> Create(Customer customer)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            customer.ID = 0;
            customer.DateServed = DateTime.Now;
            customer.UserID = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserID"]);
            db.CallCustomers.Add(customer);
        }
```

How do I solve the same in Net Core.

Comment: This should help: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Comment: Where is the issue? Are you getting `Session["UserID"]` as null?

Comment: The  `name 'Session' does not exist in the current context`

Comment: @Nickson Again, follow the examples in the documentation to configure and use the session correctly in asp.net core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-3.1